Can't figure out why this code throws a function clause error
defmodule Cidr do
  def ip_to_octets(ip) when is_binary(ip) do
    String.split(ip, ".") |> Enum.map(&String.to_integer(&1)) |> Enum.map(&Integer.to_string(&1, 2))
  end

  def ip_to_octets(_ip) do
    IO.puts("ip needs to be string")
    :error
  end

  def main(ip) do
    IO.inspect(ip_to_octets(ip))
  end

end


If I run this code by entering iex -S mix, then run recompile() and r Cidr.main("192.168.0.1") I get the error
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Code.ensure_loaded?/1    
    
    The following arguments were given to Code.ensure_loaded?/1:
    
        # 1
        "11000000"
    
    Attempted function clauses (showing 1 out of 1):
    
        def ensure_loaded?(module) when is_atom(module)
    
    (elixir 1.17.2) lib/code.ex:1822: Code.ensure_loaded?/1
    (iex 1.17.2) lib/iex/helpers.ex:465: anonymous fn/1 in IEx.Helpers.r/1
    (elixir 1.17.2) lib/enum.ex:1703: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-1-"/2
    (iex 1.17.2) lib/iex/helpers.ex:464: IEx.Helpers.r/1
    iex:16: (file)

I read it has something to do with the function clauses not matching but as far as I know all the possible paths are handled by the second ip_to_octets function.
How come I get this error? How to avoid it?

I copy pasted your code into iex and it works. Please check if the code in the question is the same as the one you're running.

Did you run r Cidr.main("192.168.0.1")? it should be just Cidr.main("192.168.0.1").

It works without the r thanks a lot :)
